convert an invalid eip-55 ethereum wallet address to valid one in py
I don't want check if it's valid I want change it to a valid one.
I use web3.to_checksum_address but system say
module web3 has no attribute to_checksum_address !
I try this but result is not good
import hashlib

def convert_invalid_eip55_address(address):
    # Convert the address to lowercase
    address = address.lower()

    # Check if the address is invalid
    if not address.startswith('0x') or len(address) != 42:
        raise ValueError("Invalid EIP-55 Ethereum wallet address")

    # Convert the address to hexadecimal
    hex_address = bytes.fromhex(address[2:]).hex()

    # Convert the hexadecimal to EIP-55 checksum
    checksum = hashlib.sha3_256(hex_address.encode()).hexdigest()[:8]

    # Convert the checksum to EIP-55 format
    eip55_checksum = ''
    for c in checksum:
        if c in '0123456789':
            eip55_checksum += c
        else:
            eip55_checksum += chr((ord(c) - 0x10) + 0x61)

    # Convert the hexadecimal address to EIP-55 format
    eip55_address = '0x' + hex_address + eip55_checksum

    return eip55_address

Example usage:
invalid_address = "0X9Ef8ee0f0d585ab9c45881672648ffd6258133d6"
                   0x9ef8ee0f0d585ab9c45881672648ffd6258133d6
valid_address = convert_invalid_eip55_address(invalid_address)
print(valid_address)  # Output: 0x1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef9c09d


always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

did you check documentation for web3? Maybe it doesn't have .to_checksum_address, or maybe it is in older or never version.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

documentation shows Web3.to_checksum_address with upper case W in word Web3 but you use web3.to_checksum_address with lower case w in word Web3. Maybe you have to use web3.Web3.to_checksum_address (module.class.function)

"Thank you, furas. Problem solved! I had an issue with uppercase and lowercase letters in my code. I must use 'web3.Web3.toChecksumAddress' instead of 'web3.toChecksumAddress'."
